# Отправка личного сообщения instagram при помощи InstaSharper

Tags: c#, .net, api, instagram-api

Нашел библиотеку `InstaSharper` в c# для взаимодействия с instagram api.
Просмотрел много методов, но никак не могу найти как отправить сообщения в директ другому пользователю (который будет указан).

Реализовал разве что похожий способ, что берет первого пользователя, кому было уже отправлено в директ и отправляет ему сообщение "Sent Message"

```
public static async void DoShow()
{
    var inboxThreads = await _instaApi.GetDirectInboxAsync();

    var firstThread = inboxThreads.Value.Inbox.Threads.FirstOrDefault();

    var sendMessageResult = await _instaApi.SendDirectMessage($"{firstThread.Users.FirstOrDefault()?.Pk}",
        firstThread.ThreadId, "Sent Message");

    Console.WriteLine(sendMessageResult.Succeeded ? "Сообщение отправлено" : "Не отправлено");
}
```

Повторюсь, подскажите как отправить конкретному пользователю в директ сообщения.

Или может похожие библиотеки, ибо в оф. instagram api не нашел ничего похожего.

Comment: На [заглавной странице либы в гитхабе](https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper) написано слово "Send direct message" - и на русский это переводится именно как ваше искомое "отправить сообщения в директ". Вероятно, это то что вы ищете (инстаграммом не пользуюсь, так что может и не оно)

Comment: Да я видел, что там это написано. Но подходящий метод как вписать конкртеонго пользователя - найти не могу

Comment: А, я понял вашу проблему. Ну пользователя допустим вы впишете так: `var user = await _instaApi.GetUserAsync("aeroflot");` а вот получится ли указать null в качестве threadId если вы никогда не переписывались с пользователем -- это попробуйте сами: `var sendMessageResult = await _instaApi.SendDirectMessage(user.Value.Pk.ToString(), null, "Sent Message");` Вроде компилируется, но проверить до конца нужны данные какого-нибудь аккаунта от инстаграмма.

Comment: Воу. Спасибо, действительно работает)

Comment: Хотел еще спросить такой момент там написано "I will not provide support to anyone who wants this API to send massive messages/likes/follows and so on". Мол, не будет предоставлять поддержку для массовых сообщений. Это получается он может как-то ограничить использования библиотеки?

Comment: Я думаю, это говорилось про поддержку в плане "отвечать на вопросы (в issue)" и "делать фичи, направленные на массовую отправку сообщений" (реализуйте самостоятельно). Никто не любит спамеров, не будьте плохим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение пользователя в документации [описано](https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper/wiki/How-to-use-library-features) так:

```
var user = await _instaApi.GetUserAsync("aeroflot");
```

Создание сообщения вы сами нашли, осталось только передать Id пользователя и выставить ThreadId (null - создание нового треда):

```
var sendMessageResult = await _instaApi.SendDirectMessage(user.Value.Pk.ToString(), null, "Sent Message");
```